# How do I specify the postgis extension version for Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I've got a Rails installation (Ruby 2.7.0p0, Rails 6.0.3.7) using Postgres 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg22.04+1). In a db console, I can run:

```
# create extension "postgis" version "3.3.2";
```

In `db/schema.rb`, I have:

```
enable_extension "postgis"
```

But when I try to run `rake db:reset`, I get the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "3.2.0"

How do I tell Rails (or `rake`) what version (3.3.2) I want to use for `postgis`? [enable_extension](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter/enable_extension) seems to take no parameters. Where does Rails even determine to use 3.2.0 in the first place?

I've also attempted to install `postgis` 3.2.0 in order to appease `rake`, but (a) that shouldn't be necessary, it seems, and (b) https://postgis.net/source/ doesn't list a "3.2.0" release.

Comment: You can use `exec_query` to perform any arbitrary SQL query in a migration. *However* - I highly doubt that the Ruby schema dumper will understand the extension version (it only actually understands a very limited subset of SQL that can be created with the migrations DSL) and that information will get lost in translation when someone tries to recreate the database from `schema.rb`. You'll most likely have to switch to SQL schema dumps. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#when-helpers-aren-t-enough

Comment: PS. All of the Rails commands should be run from Rails binary (`bin/rails db:reset`) and not `rake` as was done historically. I'm kind of suprised that you didn't get an error/warning in Rails 6.

Comment: @max, for what it's worth, I tried with both `bin/rails` and `bin/rake` and got identical errors.

Comment: @max, also, running a command as `bin/rake` allows for tab completion, whereas running it as `bin/rails` doesn't. Not a game-changer by any means, but worth noting.

Comment: Feel free to use my comment to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some statements can't be mapped cleanly to existing `ActiveRecord` methods, so I replaced the line `enable_extension "postgis"` with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('create extension "postgis" version "3.3.2";')
```

... and this allowed the task to proceed.